# How to set breakpoints on each line of code?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, console

I want to inspect how one of my chrome extensions works. I've opened its code in Chrome and would like to see which functions are called after extension starts.

How can I set breakpoints on each line of code or debug the whole code?

Comment: Close voters: This isn't a tool recommendation question. It's a question that *"..generally covers...software tools commonly used by programmers"* and is *"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"* [source](/help/on-topic) (It might be a duplicate, though I haven't found a dupe target yet, but it's not off-topic.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the Devtools **Sources** panel. Open the **Content scripts** tab, and browse to the extension script you want to debug.

[image]

Comment: In your example you set only 54's line as breakpoint. I would like to set all lines

Comment: Break on the first line and use "step over"  on each line after that.